# Build a query using dynamic where condition and a dynamic list

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dynamic, iqueryable

My Extension Method is as follows:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> TrialBatch<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> sourceQuery, List<long> Ids, Expression<Func<TSource, object>> expression)
{
    // Expected Code
}
```

expression variable receiving in the extension method will be as follows  "x => x.EmployeeID"

Is it possible to convert the expression as follows?

"x => Ids.Contains(x.EmployeeID)" so that we could combine it with the 'sourceQuery' and return the same.

This is similar to dbContext.EmployeeIDDetails.Where(x => Ids.Contains(x.EmployeeID)).ToList();
The only difference is that we will be sending the Ids and where condition("x => x.EmployeeID") dynamically with respective to tables.

I am using this type of extension method for a development purpose and also I'm curious if this is feasible. Kindly add a comment if you have any queries

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `expression` should be an `Expression<Func<TSource, long>>` if you expect to determine of the result of that selector is in the list.  Or better yet, it should be using a second generic argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [LINQKit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/LinqKit/) to allow the selector to be expanded within another expression:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIn<TSource, TProp>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> query,
    IEnumerable<TProp> list,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProp>> selector)
{
    return query.AsExpandable()
        .Where(item => list.Contains(selector.Invoke(item)));
}
```

---

If you don't want to use LinqKit, you can write your own method to compose expressions together.

The `Compose` method is as simple as replacing all instances of the parameter of the composing method with the body of the composed method:

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

This uses the following method to replace all instances of an expression with another:

```
public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}
```

And now you can write:

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> WhereIn<TSource, TProp>(
    this IQueryable<TSource> query,
    IEnumerable<TProp> sequence,
    Expression<Func<TSource, TProp>> selector)
{
    return query.Where(selector.Compose(value => sequence.Contains(value)));
}
```

Comment: Just what I was about to answer. Though I would replace `List<TProp>` with `IEnumerable<TProp>`.

Comment: Hi @Servy Is it possible to implement the same without using LINQKit?

Comment: @JagdshLK Sure, we can write a handful of helper methods that will allow us to do the same thing here.